# lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have docker daemon running on my Ubuntu 16.4 server

my server details:

> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:  Ubuntu 17.04 Release:   17.04 Codename: zesty

I'm receiving the following error:

```
aa@aaa-VirtualBox:/etc/default$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have set the http_proxy and the https_proxy beacuse i'm behind a corp proxy/firewall

Any clues how I can fix this issue?

Comment: `curl ipinfo.io` does that work for you?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes  i get the response

Comment: Have you set the proxy for docker daemon config also? or just using export variables?

Comment: I've posted an identical answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856225/2067697

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to set the proxy for Docker daemon also using environment variable. Docker run is also doing docker pull since the image doesn't exists. In your case the proxy is only applied to the docker run command, which delegates to the docker daemon which is running without proxy.

Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10_docker_proxy.conf` with below content

```
[Service]
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://1.1.1.1:111
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http://1.1.1.1:111
```

> Make sure to update the proxy as per the ones you have `1.1.1.1:111` is just an example

Then execute below commands to restart docker

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Now use your docker run command and it should work

Comment: finally this works, but not sure why this solution (https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) doesn't work.

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani, could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792954/cannot-download-docker-images-no-such-host.  I don't know the full path of docker.service.d on my windows PC.  Thanks.

Comment: In my case, docker was working fine and this error popped up all of a sudden. A simple restart with `sudo systemctl restart docker` fixed it.

Comment: After doing this i'm getting Get https://k8s-master:5000/v1/_ping: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 1.1.1.1:111: i/o timeout

Comment: In my case, based on this solution i added HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as an environment variable in my windows 10 PC. The values in it were configured to localhost:3129 where px proxy was running on port number 3129 . I was able to later pull images.

Answer (score 21):

Things you can try:

## a) Add nameserver 8.8.8.8

### Method #1

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
//change nameserver to 8.8.8.8
```

Then restart the server using

```
service docker restart
```

Note: If you don't have docker-machine installed, you can follow instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) to install it. It comes with Windows and Mac but is available for install on Linux manually.

### Method #2

[Edit /etc/docker/daemon.json](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) Or ["provide a JSON configuration in the preference panel"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32270#issuecomment-290829987) with the following information:

```
{ "dns" : [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ]}
```

Then restart the server using

```
service docker restart
```

## b) Setup Proxy

### Method #1

Edit your proxy configuration as Tarun Lalwani suggested.

Edit `/etc/default/docker` and add:

```
export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxy-host:proxy-port'
export https_proxy='https://username:password@proxy-host:proxy-port'
```

Then restart the server using

```
service docker restart
```

### Method #2

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32270#issuecomment-340709035

1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

   ```
   mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
   # For HTTP Proxy:
   vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
   # For HTTPS Proxy:
   vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf
   ```
2. Then add below content with proxy settings with it (Change to "HTTPS" for https)

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<allowed_proxy_ipv4_address>:<proxy_port_num>/"
   [Service]
   ```
3. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. `sudo systemctl restart docker`
5. Verify that the configuration has been loaded: `systemctl show --property=Environment docker`

## c) Reinstall Docker

Unfortunately the last resort, could work. Check out these github pages for more suggestions:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32270
- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1317

For me, setting up the proxy using the systemctl method was the only thing that worked.

Comment: I have Windows 7 and two physical interfaces (one of them w/o internet access) and method 1a works in that case.

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf with nameserver 8.8.8.8 and then dockerd restart

Answer (score 13):

I bumped into this error and was able to resolve by a simple restart:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Solved to me. Using Ubuntu 20.04 on wsl2

Answer (score 5):

I solve the error changing DNS server by 8.8.8.8 - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

1- Open the Ubuntu System Settings and Navigate to Network

[image]

2- Click the on the setting button next to the Network name in the list to which you are connected.

3- New Window will open with a lot number of tabs, with one of them with the label of “IPv4”.

[image]

4- Upon opening the “IPv4” Tab you will find a Field of “DNS”. Here you can write the DNS server

[image]

If you want to use more than one DNS, then you can enter and separate them with a comma.

Answer (score 5):

I tried many of the above answers, but to no avail.

Finally, this approach worked for me:

```
docker logout
docker login
```

I have no idea why though.

Comment: Happened to me after resetting Docker settings, I was still connected but logout / login worked liked a charm, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Docker Settings -> Proxies -> Manual proxy configuration**.

Set the proxy details in the input and apply.

Restart the docker. This will fix the issue.

[image: http://19.12.1.40:83]

Answer (score 1):

Simplified detailed solution in case you are having this problem in windows is as below:
right click on network
open network and internet setting
In advanced network setting, click on change adapter options
right click on your network or wifi connection
click on properties
in Networking tab click on Internet protocal version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or ipv6
In general, click on use the following DNS server address and add 8.8.8.8 on preferred DNS server

Answer (score 1):

FOr windows going to resoureces -Network and changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 did the trick. ALso make sure to restart after chaning.
[image]

Comment: there are no DNS server settings in the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in Docker Desktop for windows, running on top of WSL2 behind a corporate proxy.

After trying the above solutions without no success, the problem was resolved by adding *.docker.com to the Proxy bypass.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a bad config entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` that prevented docker from resolving container registries.

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, my hosts line looked like this:

```
hosts:      files myhostname
```

After changing the hosts property to default value, everything worked.

```
# default value for hosts
hosts:      files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

After changing the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, make sure to restart `systemd-resolved.service`.

Answer (score -1):

Configure Docker to start on boot

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```