# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am new to dockers. When I am running the docker pull sonarqube I am getting the following error.

**Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial TCP: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host**

Can you please let me know why I am getting the error and how can I rectify this.

Comment: `192.168.0.0/16` is reserved, local IP space and https://registry-1.docker.io should not be pointing to it; what happens when you ping `registry-1.docker.io` ?

Comment: I would suggest you to change DNS to 8.8.8.8. But it may not solve the problem in some cases.

Comment: Proxy was the issue in my case

Comment: I tried a few times the same command and it worked eventually. I did nothing. It's like the host has limited slots to serve and I had to be lucky or something.

Comment: the Given IP implements that you are inside a Virtualmachine, I think the Problem is really that you have no Internet Connection. Check your Networkports for the VM, you need a NAT Port to be connected to the Internet.

All given Answers are right actually but I guess this case Is realy about a missing Port

Comment: For me it was fixed after a re-install of Docker. I tried with namespaces etc. but Docker reinstall worked.

Answer (score 125):

I had similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04
and manage to solve it by adding more `nameservers`

You can try too.

1. Open config file `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and add the following under existing nameservers

   `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

   `nameserver 8.8.4.4`
2. run following commands to restart daemon and docker service

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

   `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Now try to pull image you want `docker pull sonarqube`

Comment: Consider this as the correct answer. Solved only with this.

Comment: simply following step 2 worked for me

Comment: Adding 8.8.8.8 as one of the nameservers fixed the issue

Answer (score 37):

I was able to resolve by running the below command.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: In Windows 10 restarting Docker through the GUI was enough; I didn't need to run any command through the WSL2 terminal

Answer (score 36):

In my case on a Mac, only a restart of the docker-machine did the work:

```
docker-machine restart
```

Uninstalling docker did not work! Just the above restart is enough!

Comment: This worked for me as well using windows docker toolbox

Comment: Same here. Just restart fixed my issue

Comment: Docker machine shouldn't really be used anymore

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

And change nameserver to `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, for me I was behind my office proxy and docker was not picking up the proxy set for terminal. To fix this, i have to set the proxy in docker settings window, which can be accessed from

task bar -> docker -> settings
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve this issue, by logging into docker.

```
sudo docker login
Enter your login credentials 
sudo docker pull 'yourImageName'
```

Comment: How would this fix network resolution issue?

Answer (score 5):

in windows, just restart the docker, it worked for me.
Go to Docker Desktop dashboard, click on the icon with setting icon and click restart

Answer (score 4):

You need to add to your **/etc/hosts** in terminal write

$ **sudo nano /etc/hosts**

add below line and save it, try to run command and it will be working

```
34.228.211.243  registry-1.docker.io
```

Answer (score 4):

I just restarted and it works fine again!

Answer (score 4):

This could also be a DNS issue. Altering your nameservers will most likely resolve it, if is indeed related to your DNS.

You can verify the issue with: `curl -vvv  https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` for a more detailed path.

If you are on ubuntu 18.04 or higher `/etc/resolve.conf` won't do the trick, they moved network management to [NetPlan](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/4240/how-to-set-dns-search-order-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan/) configs.

Add the google nameservers to your configuration (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

*find your network adapter name with `ip a`*

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
      [network adapter name]:
              addresses: ...
              gateway4: ...
              nameservers:
                      addresses:
                              - 8.8.8.8
                              - 8.8.4.4
                      search: []
```

And run `sudo netplan apply`

Answer (score 4):

Disable experiment features and try again does the trick.
Otherwise add the config below to daemon.json

```
"dns": [
    "8.8.8.8",
    "8.8.4.4"
  ]
```

Comment: This response lacks the full file path, structure, and info about having to restart the docker service afterward.
So, go to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, edit the file with admin privileges, add this entry, remember about surrounding braces `{}` since it's a json file, save and then run `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 3):

If your machine are located within the Great China area or using related Virtual Server, add `Registry Mirrors` to help your bypass the complex network router.

Or your can set a http_proxy for your docker configuration, referencing this link: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Answer (score 3):

make sure that your server is not located in the following areas:

> Docker is a US company, we must comply with US export control regulations. In an  effort to comply with these, we now block all IP addresses that are located in Cuba,  Iran, North Korea, Republic of Crimea, Sudan, and Syria.

Comment: Please provide source of quote

Answer (score 2):

Things that might work:

1. Check your proxy settings
2. Restart docker
3. Go to your docker settings and check if you're signed in to docker hub, if you aren't, sign in and try again (This worked for me)

Comment: This is not explicit enough about how to check the proxy settings

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you are not logged in too, it happened to me. Problem gone after I logged in

Comment: Logged in to what? How?

Comment: To Docker of course

Comment: Docker hub? Amazon / Google / Github Docker Registry? Your own registry?

Comment: When It happened to me, I fixed it with loginning via Docker Desktop, Command line was giving that error when I was trying to pull without login

Answer (score 1):

A restart of your internet connection might solve this.

Comment: Don't know why it got a downvote. In my case, I got this error when the internet connection was disconnected. Worked fine, after reconnecting.






Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on ***.***.**.*:**: no such host

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was resolved by changing the DNS settings in Wi-Fi network.

By modifying the DNS server to ‍‍‍`8.8.8.8` (Google Public DNS) from `192.168.1.1` it worked

[image: DNS change in MAC]

Comment: It solved my long-time issues. Thank you @santhosh

Answer (score 0):

In China, Add 114.114.114.114 to resolv.conf fixed it.
sudo echo "nameserver 114.114.114.114" >> /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, I restarted docker and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error & I solved it by executing the below-mentioned commands, If you are working on the windows version, you can try these commands
Steps to be followed : Open the command prompt & execute these commands,

```
set http_proxy="http://user:pwd@proxyurl.com:port"

set https_proxy="https://user:pwd@proxy-url.com:port"
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was tha ti was behind a corporate proxy and hence i was unable to reach the registry-1.docker.io.

Solution:

I bypassed this URL registry-1.docker.io in the proxy server for following

1. SSL bypass
2. Authentication Bypass.

Then i configured the proxy settings in docker.service file in RHEL server as

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:443"
NO_PROXY=“tnd-harbor.india.airtel.itm,10.241.99.232,
registry-1.docker.io/v2/”
```

Make sure the HTTPS_PROXY protocol is http.

By doing this i was able to fetch images.

Answer (score 0):

After trying most solutions mentioned on this page nothing worked for me.
Weirdly mine worked after updating docker desktop from some 4.16.x to 4.17.1
That update restarted docker and might've fixed whatever the issue was.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was due to eval $(minikube docker-env) in my terminal .bash_profile/.profile

When this runs it sets

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.64.4:2376"
```

To fix I ran

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

I also removed **eval $(minikube docker-env)** from my shell env.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried so many solutions like restarting-docker, setting buildkit to false in docker-Engine setting tab (Docker Windows), etc, all to no avail. When I viewed my containers and images in Docker-window, the list were empty.

I re-installed docker and everything was fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error. Tried a few things like restarting the server, checking configuration etc...
Finally, it got resolved by adding proxies (since I was using it inside my organization network)

Comment: How did you add proxies

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue with a different solution. The issue was that the internet wasn't connected. That's another thing to check if none of these fix it for you!