# Unable to pull images no such host on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I tried to build a docker file on Windows OS. But i got this instead.

```
muhammad.iqbal@IQBAL MINGW64 /d/DockerTest
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 73.36 MB
Step 1/3 : FROM php:7.1.27-apache
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host
```

I have tried to restart and relaunch docker application but nothings change.
i have read this and this. but it's on LInux OS, but how to do it on Windows OS.

[Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580528/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-dial-tcp-look)

[lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036152/lookup-registry-1-docker-io-no-such-host)

Comment: It seems registry-1.docker.io points to 192.168.65.1:53, are you sure your DNS configurations are correct? Are you using a proxy or VPN ?

Comment: @PierreB. yes, i am really sure i didn't use any VPN. Because i could run it properly, but sometimes, i couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so just like Pierre B. comment, at the time of that issue, i was using my office's VPN. So it's pretty simple, just turn of the VPN and tried to pull it again.

But i don't know what's the reason unable to pull any images when i am using the office's VPN.