# docker installation problem with windows 10 home + wsl

Tags: docker

I installed wsl2 on windows 10 home
(with ubuntu latest version)
okay
then the docker community version for windows
with docker run hello-world
I have the following error

PS C:\Users\patri> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: read udp 192.168.65.3:43193->192.168.65.1:53: i/o timeout.
See 'docker run --help'.
help please

Comment: just 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
for ubuntu ...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your domain name servers. You mentioned you have just installed it, just to be sure, have you restarted your computer since then? When a similar issue was raised, [it was one of the most popular fixes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407530/13235887)

If that doesn't solve your problem, I'd recommend you change the DNS of your Docker network adapter, labeled `vEthernet(DockerNAT)` in your network management control panel, to `8.8.8.8` or/and `8.8.4.4` (Google's DNS Servers), this should fix the problem.

[Here's](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22635) the documentation on a related Github issue, [and a few more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056365/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-b) theories/explanations on the problem.