# docker run hello-world error: docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/" lookup proxy.hostname on 8.8.8.8:53: no such

Tags: docker, networking, netplan

I just installed docker in Ubuntu 22.04. The command:

```
docker run hello-world
```

displays the error message:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.hostname on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I already did what is described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624272/3310237):

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
      wlx00e1b0217858:
              access-points:
                "CASADOMAURAO":
                   password: "*******"
              addresses: [192.168.0.200/24]
              routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 192.168.0.1
              nameservers:
                      addresses:
                              - 8.8.8.8
                              - 8.8.4.4
                      search: []
```

If I run `sudo netplan apply` I get no error message, but the docker error persists.