# Adding `networkingMode=mirrored` to `.wslconfig` results in Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": connection refused

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I tried adding these 2 lines to `.wslconfig` below:

#### .wslconfig

```bash
[wsl2]
localhostforwarding=true
networkingMode=mirrored
firewall=true
```

And I got this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.2.3:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:60721->127.0.2.3:53: read: connection refused.

If I remove it, like this:

#### .wslconfig

```bash
[wsl2]
localhostforwarding=true
```

Then this command `docker run --rm -ti -p 80:80 nginx` works fine. And I can also run `docker compose build` to fetch images & it downloads them correctly without mirrored networking.

Since [this one answer is everywhere recommended as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580528/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-dial-tcp-look), I added it to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file but it automatically changes everytime which I don't want to change otherwise if I change something in my `.wslconfig`, then it won't get updated & might cause future issues.

I added Google's DNS servers `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4` but it replaced it now with this:

```bash
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 322.16.449.1
```

where `nameserver` ip `322.16.449.1` is wsl ip which is the same as the ip when i perform `ipconfig` command & it shows it under ipv4 under wsl hyper-v firewall.

However, even if I add Google's IP, it doesn't work for some reason.

How do I solve that issue?