# No such host: registry-1.docker.io

Tags: docker, docker-compose

> **NOTE:** this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036152/lookup-registry-1-docker-io-no-such-host), I am not doing any proxying.

I'm in a CentOS 7 Vagrant VM:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
$ uname -r
3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

I have the latest Docker and Docker Compose installed and running:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
$ id
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),993(docker) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

My host can resolve `registry-1.docker.io`:

```
$ dig +short registry-1.docker.io
52.22.201.61
34.200.28.105
34.205.207.96
34.233.151.211
34.206.236.31
34.201.236.93
52.206.40.44
52.22.67.152
```

However, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN /bin/true
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
ERROR: Service 'trusty' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: no such host
```

Even trying to `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:14.04 bash` yields the same DNS issue. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your host OS? Does `registry-1.docker.io` get resolved from w/i the Vagrant VM?

Comment: Host OS is Ubuntu 16.04. If I hardcode 8.8.8.8 as my resolver in the Vagrant VM, I still experience the problem.