# Cannot download Docker images - no such host

Tags: docker

I have a web app on my home PC, which uses Docker.  It works as expected.

I have installed Docker on my work PC.  So far I have run: `docker run hello-world` and I see an expected result:

[image]

I then try: `docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo:tag` and I see this:

[image]

I have spent a lot of time looking into this.  So far I have tried (in Docker for Windows Settings):

1) In Proxies; check 'Manual proxy configuration' and specify: http://proxy1:8080 as http and https proxy server (this is what is specified in Internet Settings).

2) In Network specify a fixed DNS server of: 8.8.8.8.

This has made no difference.  What is the problem?  Do I need to pass my username and password to the proxy server? I am confused why the command in screenshot 1 works as expected whilst the command in screenshot 2 does not.

I have Docker for Windows on a Windows 10 PC.  I am using Linux containers.

Comment: I hate to suggest this, try installing a different (newer/older) version of docker

Comment: The port 53 is a dns server, so it tries to lookup the proxy at the dns server 192.168.65.1. So it seems that setting the dns-server did not go well.  Maybe it helps if you share the network settings of the docker application..

Comment: This may have to do with a proxy which needs auth, check if you can find more information on using proxies which need auth